# How to kill (stop/clear) browser.driver.wait() in protractor?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a problem when use `wait()` in protractor.
This is my code:

```
var timeOut = function(callback) {
        browser.driver.wait(function() {
            callback();
        }, 5000);

    };

this.Then(/^input userName "([^"]*)", password "([^"]*)" and click login$/, function (userName, password, next) {
        login();

        function login() {
            var userNameElm = by.css('[id="userName"]');

            browser.driver.isElementPresent(userNameElm).then(function(exist) {
                if (exist) {
                    browser.driver.findElement(userNameElm).sendKeys("oh my gold!");
                    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[id="pass"]')).sendKeys("pass test");
                    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login')).click().then(function(){
                       return next();
                    });
                } else {
                    timeOut(login);
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

And i got a error `Message: Failed: Wait timed out after`. The problem occur because It will call `timeOut(login);` forever.
How can I kill wait() function.Thanks.

Comment: Refer https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md for learn about timeouts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `setTimeout` or `browser.driver.wait`, you should just use a `browser.driver.sleep` for this case:

```
login();

function login() {
    var userNameElm = by.css('[id="userName"]');

    return browser.driver.isElementPresent(userNameElm).then(function(exist) {
        if (exist) {
            browser.driver.findElement(userNameElm).sendKeys("oh my gold!");
            browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[id="pass"]')).sendKeys("pass test");
            return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login')).click();
        } else {
            return browser.driver.sleep(5000).then(function() {
                return login();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at protractors asynchronosity (is that a valid word?) and the resulting promise chains to reflect synchronous-like behaviour, therefore assuming control over your step order and valid results.

suggestion:

```
this.Then(/^input userName "([^"]*)", password "([^"]*)" and click login$/, function (userName, password) {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css('[id="userName"]'))
           .then(function(element) {
                if (element != null) {
                    return browser.driver.findElement(userNameElm)
                       .sendKeys("oh my gold!");
                } else {
                    //fail- element not found
                    return false; 
                }

           })
           .then(function(){
               return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('[id="pass"]'))
                   .sendKeys("pass test");
           })
           .then(function(){
               return browser.driver.findElement(by.id('login'))
                   .click(); 
           })
        });
    }
});
```

the whole block will timeout if you do not make it to the end of the promise chain, given by the allScriptsTimeout from the protractor config.